# EntityFramwork compatibility with .net framework 4.7.2 projects and .net standard 2.0 project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure-functions, .net-standard-2.0, .net-4.7.2

I have shared project that use entity framework 6.4 and it represents data access layer in other projects with .net framework 4.7.2.

I also have created an azure function version 2 project. The framework is .net standard 2.0 which supports .net core 2, as it is needed for azure functions.

The problem happens when I want to use that shared entity framework project in azure function. Since EntityFramework 6.4 is not supported on .net standard 2.0

I am looking for a solution to upgrade or downgrade or even framework change to use that shared entity framework project in azure function and all other projects.

Comment: Entity Framework 6.4 is supported on netstandard 2.1 but not 2.0. Can you enable multi-targetting in your data layer project?

Comment: Then I should upgrade azure function project framework to .net standard 2.1, and I think it means I lost all compatibility with other projects with .net framework 4.7.2. I think ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework 6.4 is compatible with netstandard 2.1, but not 2.0, meaning it requires dotnet core 3.0 at minimum.

But if you can upgrade your azure function project to target core 3.0, you can enable multi-targeting in your data layer project.

Open the `csproj` file and replace :

```xml
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
```

by

```xml
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.1;net472</TargetFrameworks>
```

Note the change from `TargetFramework` to `TargetFrameworks`, this is important!

This will enable the project to be referenced by projects targeting the full framework (4.7.2 and above) as well as anything supported by net standard 2.1.

Comment: yes, it can let me to reference the data layer project in azure function project, but I also have some other shared projects on .net framework 4.7.2. Does it mean I need to migrate all of them to .net core?

Comment: No, this is where the multi-targeting aspect comes in. This project can now be referenced by both .net core and full framework projects.

Answer (score 1):

If you use v1 version of Azure Functions there are less compatibility issues, EF for instance is supported but you might still run into issues with other dependencies.

I have had great success in the past by creating V2 functions that operate as a "front end" that post messages to Event Hubs or a Service bus Queue. Then use a continuous web job to process these queued messages in .net framework code, which I now refer to as the "legacy" portion of my solution.

Another option is to use a REST API that runs in .net fx, this will keep your functions lightweight as they only need to call endpoints in the API